# How to fillMaxSize() the Box() inside row - Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to align the button in the BottomEnd of the Box in Row (In the BottonEnd of the bellow Card). I have Card with Row who is devided in two parts - Card and Box, and I want the Box to fill max of the rest of the row. I cannot implement it how I would wanted. Bellow I attached the visualization of the current code.

[image].

```
@Composable
fun ProductItem(product: ProductModel, onItemClick: () -> Unit, onAddToCardButton: () -> Unit) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(7.dp)
            .clickable { onItemClick() },
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f),
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
                elevation = 2.dp
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_splash_screen),
                    contentDescription = "Image of ${product.name}",
                )
            }
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(2f)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .padding(6.dp)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            ) {
                Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopStart)) {
                    Text(
                        text = "${product.number}. ${product.name}",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = product.ingredients, fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic
                    )
                }

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
                    onClick = {
                        onAddToCardButton()
                    },
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                ) {
                    if (product.type == "pizza") {
                        Text(text = "od ${String.format("%.2f", product.price[0])} zł")
                    } else {
                        Text(text = "${String.format("%.2f", product.price[0])} zł")

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect you display this item in `LazyColumn` or inside a vertical scrollable.

`Modifier.fillMaxHeight` doesn't work in this case, because parent height constraint is equal to infinity.

To solve this you ofc can use a static value, but in this case [intrinsic measurements](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements) can be used to wrap content size.

Add `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` to your `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good to me at first sight, even tried it and the button is on the bottom right corner. **Where do you define the height of your ProductItem card?**

Maybe you can try to define it in the code you provided by changing the

```
.fillMaxSize()
```

modifier to

```
.fillMaxWidth()
.requiredHeight(**.dp)
```

at your first Card composable.

So it would look something like this:

```
@Composable
fun ProductItem(product: ProductModel, onItemClick: () -> Unit, onAddToCardButton: () -> Unit) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .requiredHeight(**.dp)
            .padding(7.dp)
            .clickable { onItemClick() },
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I wanted the height of the main Card to not be static. I wanted to adjust it by the size of the image in inner Card, which is specified by .weight(1f) i guess. But I tried your idea, and it fits good with .requiredHeight(130.dp).  Now the Box fillMaxHeight. Thanks.

Comment: If you want your height a "bit more dynamic" you can pass it down through your ProductItem composable as a parameter.  `ProductItem(...,cardHeight: Int = 130, ...) { Card(modifier = ....requiredHeight(cardHeight.dp)` . Maybe there was a misunderstanding: if you write `.weight()` to a child inside of a Row it won't affect the height of the child only the width. (And if you write it inside a Column it won't affect the width of the child only the height).

Answer (score 0):

As Phil Dukhov answered `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` works for me.

Just set the modifier to the Root element in your Row. In your case it's Card (change `.fillMaxWidth()` to `.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)`):

```
Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
            .padding(7.dp)
            .clickable { onItemClick() },
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        elevation = 4.dp
    )
```